# How to set default value to 'null' in Dataset parsed from RDD[String] applying Case Class as schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am parsing JSON strings from a given `RDD[String]` and try to convert it into a `Dataset` with a given `case class`. However, when the JSON string does not contain all required fields of the `case class` I get an Exception that the missing column could not be found.

How can I define default values for such cases?

I tried defining default values in the `case class` but that did not solve the problem. I am working with Spark 2.3.2 and Scala 2.11.12.

This code is working fine

```scala
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

case class SchemaClass(a: String, b: String)

val jsonData: String = """{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}"""
val jsonRddString: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(jsonData))

import spark.implicits._
val ds = spark.read.json(jsonRddString).as[SchemaClass]
```

When I run this code

```scala
val jsonDataIncomplete: String = """{"a": "foo"}"""
val jsonIncompleteRddString: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(jsonDataIncomplete))

import spark.implicits._
val dsIncomplete = spark.read.json(jsonIncompleteRddString).as[SchemaClass]

dsIncomplete.printSchema()
dsIncomplete.show()
```

I get the following Exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`b`' given input columns: [a];
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:333)
[...]
```

Interestingly, the default value "null" is applied when json strings are parsed from a file as the example given in the Spark documentation on [Datasets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#creating-datasets) is shown:

```scala
val path = "examples/src/main/resources/people.json"
val peopleDS = spark.read.json(path).as[Person]
peopleDS.show()
// +----+-------+
// | age|   name|
// +----+-------+
// |null|Michael|
// |  30|   Andy|
// |  19| Justin|
// +----+-------+
```

Content of the json file

```sh
{"name":"Michael"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19}
```

Comment: add diff type to columns, please, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Sathiyan S led me to the following solution (presenting it here as it did not completely solved my problems but served as the pointer to the right direction):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType}

// created expected schema
val schema = Encoders.product[SchemaClass].schema

// convert all fields as nullable
val newSchema = StructType(schema.map {
  case StructField( c, t, _, m) ⇒ StructField( c, t, nullable = true, m)
})

// apply expected and nullable schema for parsing json string            
session.read.schema(newSchema).json(jsonIncompleteRddString).as[SchemaClass]
```

Benefits:

- All missing fields are set to `null`, independent of data type
- Additional fields in the json string, which are not part of the `case class` will be ignored

Answer (score 1):

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, Encoders, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit}

object JsonDF extends App {


  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class SchemaClass(a: String, b: Int)

  val jsonDataIncomplete: String = """{"a": "foo", "m": "eee"}"""
  val jsonIncompleteRddString: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(jsonDataIncomplete))

  val dsIncomplete = spark.read.json(jsonIncompleteRddString)  // .as[SchemaClass]

  lazy val schema: StructType    = Encoders.product[SchemaClass].schema
  lazy val fields: Array[String] = schema.fieldNames
  lazy val colNames: Array[Column]  = fields.map(col(_))

  val sch = dsIncomplete.schema
  val schemaDiff = schema.diff(sch)
  val rr = schemaDiff.foldLeft(dsIncomplete)((acc, col) => {
    acc.withColumn(col.name, lit(null).cast(col.dataType))
  })



  val schF = dsIncomplete.schema
  val schDiff = schF.diff(schema)

  val rrr = schDiff.foldLeft(rr)((acc, col) => {
    acc.drop(col.name)
  })
    .select(colNames: _*)


}
```

Comment: it wont work for columns of different type than string

Comment: add diff  type, please, see @QuickSilver

Comment: added drop columns @mike

Answer (score 1):

You can now skip loading json as RDD and then reading as DF to directly
`val dsIncomplete = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonDataIncomplete).toDS)` if you are using Spark 2.2+

1. Load your JSON data
2. Extract your schema from case class or define it manually
3. Get the missing field list
4. Default the value to `lit(null).cast(col.dataType)` for missing column.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType}

object DefaultFieldValue {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._
    val jsonDataIncomplete: String = """{"a": "foo"}"""
    val dsIncomplete = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonDataIncomplete).toDS)
    val schema: StructType = Encoders.product[SchemaClass].schema

    val fields: Array[StructField] = schema.fields

    val outdf = fields.diff(dsIncomplete.columns).foldLeft(dsIncomplete)((acc, col) => {
      acc.withColumn(col.name, lit(null).cast(col.dataType))
    })

    outdf.printSchema()
    outdf.show()


  }
}

case class SchemaClass(a: String, b: Int, c: String, d: Double)
```

Comment: functions.lit(null)) ??? try printSchema(). and you can see  b: null (nullable = true) - is not correct

Comment: updated the ans to map to particular type @mvasyliv

Answer (score 1):

It will work the same way if you have different json strings in the same RDD. When you have only one which is not matching with the schema then it will throw error.

Eg.

```
val jsonIncompleteRddString: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(jsonDataIncomplete, jsonData))

import spark.implicits._
val dsIncomplete = spark.read.json(jsonIncompleteRddString).as[SchemaClass]

dsIncomplete.printSchema()
dsIncomplete.show()

scala> dsIncomplete.show()
+---+----+
|  a|   b|
+---+----+
|foo|null|
|foo| bar|
+---+----+
```

One way you can do is instead converting it as[Person] you can build schema(StructType) from it and apply it while reading the json files,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

val schema = Encoders.product[Person].schema

val path = "examples/src/main/resources/people.json"
val peopleDS = spark.read.schema(schema).json(path).as[Person]
peopleDS.show
+-------+----+
|   name| age|
+-------+----+
|Michael|null|
+-------+----+
```

Content of the code file is,

```
{"name":"Michael"}
```